# Docker Compose on Crunchy Postgres and Hasura Graphql Engine - Database URL settings

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, hasura

If the question is unclear or there isn't enough information please let me know, as I did my best to present my issue from my understanding...

I'm trying to configure Crunchy Postgres image with Hasura GraphQL Engine, I tried changing the hostname as what the documentation suggested but it's not connecting at all to my Crunchy Postgres image.

Doc links:

https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/deployment/docker/index.html

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hasura/graphql-engine/master/install-manifests/docker-compose/docker-compose.yaml

https://hub.docker.com/r/crunchydata/crunchy-postgres/

My Docker-Compose File:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  unipgdb:
    image: crunchydata/crunchy-postgres:centos7-11.1-2.3.0
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - ./config/postgres/cpg-env.list
    volumes:
      - unipgdata_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - unicausalapi

  graphql-engine:
    image: hasura/graphql-engine:v1.0.0-alpha37
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      - "unipgdb"
    restart: always
    environment:
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL: postgres://user:password@postgres:5432/unipgdb
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE: "true" # set to "false" to disable console
      ## uncomment next line to set an access key
      # HASURA_GRAPHQL_ACCESS_KEY: mysecretaccesskey
    networks:
      - unicausalapi

  # For Hasura engine
  caddyhasura:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: caddyhasura-Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - graphql-engine
    networks:
      - unicausalapi
      - unicausalpublic
      - unicausalnetwork

volumes:
  static_volume:  # <-- declare the static volume
  media_volume:  # <-- declare the media volume
  unipgdata_volume:
      external: true

networks:
   unicausalpublic:
      external: true
   unicausalnetwork:
      external: true
   unicausalapi:
      external: true
```

In the Caddyfile for caddyhasura service, it is just a reverse proxy on the container graphql-engine, so it shouldn't affect my issue.

I think I'm configuring the HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL incorrectly with hostname because I'm not sure what to put for using crunchy-postgres:centos7 image.

I get this error in Docker Log

[image: hasura error]

How do I configure this to work with my docker-compose file using those images?

```
HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL: postgres://user:password@postgres:5432/unipgdb
```

Any thoughts on what to do to try and solve my problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Crunchy Postgres container's name is `unipgdb`, the hostname for the container will be the same. Instead of `postgres` as hostname, you should use this.

So, your database url will become

`HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL: postgres://user:password@unipgdb:5432/unipgdb`

If your username or password contains special characters (like $, #, @ etc.) make sure you URL encode and use them in the URL. ref: https://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php

E.g. If password is `secretPassW$or#`, it should be entered as `secretPassW%24or%23`